# С++ как вставить столбец данных в консольное приложение

Tags: c++

Вот есть простой код

```
 #include
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
char uin[19];
cin >> uin;
cout << uin[3];
cin.get();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

он выводит третий символ
как сделать возможность разом вставить в консольное приложение столбца из нескольких строк
нужно вставить

```
1234567891123456789
3745983495039485030
7349828765928475934
```

количество строк может быть разным
Чтобы результат был

```
1234567891123456789
4
3745983495039485030
5
7349828765928475934
9
```

и увидеть результат по каждой строке

Comment: А что за цифры в последнем примере `4,5,9`?

Comment: ну это какой должен быть результат я ввожу 1234567891123456789
3745983495039485030
7349828765928475934 и программа выдает результат 1234567891123456789
4
3745983495039485030
5
7349828765928475934
9

Comment: То есть, вы вводите три строки через пробел, и там где был пробелы, вставить символы `4,5,9`?

Comment: нет нужна вставить в приложение столбец например из EXCEl или WoRD без разницы в каждой строке столбца будет  19 символов и нужна например задать  покажи третий символ каждой строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, это то, что вам нужно:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;
    string str[N];
   
    
    for (auto& i : str)
    {
        cin >> i;
    }

    system("cls");

    for (auto& i : str)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        cout << i[3] << endl;
    }
 
   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```